# 'type' object is not subscriptable when reversing list

Tags: python-3.x, string, list, reverse

having difficulty with this code; I've tried below as well as .reverse(), reversed() and slicing as below. I keep getting the error as above and I am at a loss as to what the problem is. any clues as to what my major malfunction is here?

function is given a list of numbers. script reverses all the numbers in the list and returns the list. any number ending with 0 needs trailing '0' to be removed prior to reversing the number. None of the numbers in the number_list will be less than 1.

below is my code.

```
def reverse_number_in_list(number_list:list)->list:
while True:
        if 0 in number_list:
            [i.strip('0') for i in number_list]
            return list[::-1]
        else:
            return list[::-1]
```

Comment: return `number_list[::-1]`

Comment: `list` is a built-in function for Python. I'd recommend not shadowing it in code that you write.